# How to setup kafka-kinesis-connector if I use a Kafka container?

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, amazon-kinesis

I'm a little bit confused. I've been following this to get started and the installation method.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kinesis-kafka-connector-msk/

1. Setup AWS cli and configure it
2. Install maven
3. Compile connector
4. Set classpath with the jar generated
5. Set up the properties file of the connector
6. FYI: I have a docker-compose that creates all my containers (kafka, mqtt, etc.)
   (all of the above is setup on-premise)

And then, I executed all this on my machine itself and not on the Kafka container, so for the last step how would that work when I try to run it standalone?

```
version: '3'
services:  
  nodered:
    container_name: nodered
    image: nodered/node-red
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    volumes:
      - ./nodered:/data
    depends_on:
      - mosquitto
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Toronto
      - NODE_RED_ENABLE_PROJECTS=true
    restart: always
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    container_name: mqtt
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
    volumes:
      - "./mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config"
      - "./mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data"
      - "./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log"
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Toronto
    user: "${PUID}:${PGID}"
  portainer:
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    container_name: portainer
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./portainer/portainer_data:/data"
    image: portainer/portainer-ce
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "zookeeper_data:/data"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.0
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9093:9093"
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/data"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=10.0.0.129:2181
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=10.0.0.129
      - JMX_PORT=9093
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS=1
      - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=10000000
      - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=10000000
      - KAFKA_GROUP_MAX_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS=60000
      - KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS=2
      - KAFKA_DELETE_RETENTION_MS=1000
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    restart: on-failure
  cmak:
    image:  hlebalbau/kafka-manager:1.3.3.16
    container_name: kafka-manager
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9080:9080"
    environment:
      - ZK_HOSTS=10.0.0.129
      - APPLICATION_SECRET=letmein
    command: -Dconfig.file=/kafka-manager/conf/application.conf -Dapplication.home=/kafkamanager -Dhttp.port=9080

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
```

1. I guess I have to go into my Kafka container and run the below code, but how can I reference by machine path... I'm stuck here or perhaps I'm missing something:

   ./bin/connect-standalone.sh {{path_from_machine_where_jar_is}}/kinesis-kafka-connector/config/worker.properties {{path_from_machine_where_jar_is}}/kinesis-kafka-connector/config/kinesis-streams-kafka-
   connector.properties
2. Or I have to run all the previous steps in my Kafka container directly...

I was thinking of just doing this, copy my jar file and just moving it in my kafka container.

```
docker cp /hostfile  (container_id):/(to_the_place_you_want_the_file_to_be)
```

Thank you!

Comment: By the way, you should not use IP addresses between containers

Comment: Yep, I plan on changing that and using env variables.

Answer (score 0):

> guess I have to go into my Kafka container and run the below code

No. Containers should only run one process, which is kafka server.

So, either you download Kafka locally and run the Connect scripts from your host.

Or you simply add a new container for Kafka Connect, which will run Connect distributed mode, rather than standalone.

In either case, yes, you need to copy (or mount) the jar into Connect's plugin path

Alternatively, run MSK rather than Kinesis and produce your Kafka data there rather than locally.

Comment: My MQTT and Kafka need to run on-prem (locally) to handle offline mode and stream data accordingly.

Comment: Okay, fine. As mentioned, you can run Kafka Connect on your host directly, or as a container